# bison only reads one line

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm doing a simple calculator with flex and bison but it only reads the first line of the input file.
this is my bison code:

```
%{

    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include <math.h>

    #include "symtab.h"



    extern int yylex(void);

    extern char *yytext;

    extern int num_linea;

    extern FILE *yyin;

    void yyerror(char *s);



%}





%union{

    struct{

        char *lexema;

        int lenght;

        int line;

    }ident;

}

%union{

    struct{

        int integer;

        float real;

        char *string;

        int type;

        }num;

}

%union{

    int num_int;

}

%union{

    float num_float;

}

%token <ident> IDENT

%token <num> LIT_INT

%token <num> LIT_FLOAT

%token <num> CADENA

%token PARENTESIS1

%token PARENTESIS2

%token OP_SUM

%token OP_REST

%token OP_MULT

%token OP_DIV

%token OP_MOD

%token OP_POW

%token ASSIGN

%token NX_LINE

%token INVALID_TOKEN



%type <num> expr

%type <num> term

%type <num> factor

%type <num> primary

%type <num> linea



%%

linea   :   IDENT ASSIGN expr NX_LINE   {/*sym_enter($1.lexema,(void *)&$3)*/;}

        |   OP_SUM expr NX_LINE {if($2.type==0) {

                            printf("El valor es %d. \n", $2.integer);

                        } else if($2.type==1) {

                            printf("El valor es %f. \n", $2.real);

                        }}

        |   OP_REST expr NX_LINE    {if($2.type==0) {

                            printf("El valor es %d. \n", -$2.integer);

                        } else if($2.type==1) {

                            printf("El valor es %f. \n", -$2.real);

                        }}

        |   expr NX_LINE    {if($1.type==0) {

                            printf("El valor es entero y es %d. \n", $1.integer);

                        } else if($1.type==1) {

                            printf("El valor es un float y es %f. \n", $1.real);

                        } else if($1.type==2) {

                            printf("El valor es un string y es %s. \n", $1.string);

                        }}

        ;

expr    :   expr OP_SUM term    {if($1.type==0 && $3.type==0) {

                                            $$.type=0;

                                            $$.integer=$1.integer+$3.integer;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.real+$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==0 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.integer+$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==0) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.real+$3.integer;

                                    }else if($1.type==0 && $3.type==2) {

                                        $$.type=2;

                                        $$.string=malloc(sizeof($3.string)+sizeof($1.integer));

                                        sprintf($$.string,"%d%s",$1.integer,$3.string);

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==2) {

                                        $$.type=2;

                                        $$.string=malloc(sizeof($3.string)+sizeof($1.real));

                                        sprintf($$.string,"%f%s",$1.real,$3.string);

                                    }else if($3.type==0 && $1.type==2) {

                                        $$.type=2;

                                        $$.string=malloc(sizeof($1.string)+sizeof($3.integer));

                                        sprintf($$.string,"%s%d",$1.string,$3.integer);

                                    } else if($3.type==1 && $1.type==2) {

                                        $$.type=2;

                                        $$.string=malloc(sizeof($3.real)+sizeof($1.string));

                                        sprintf($$.string,"%s%f",$1.string,$3.real);

                                    }}

        |   expr OP_REST term   {if($1.type==0 && $3.type==0) {

                                            $$.type=0;

                                            $$.integer=$1.integer-$3.integer;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.real-$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==0 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.integer-$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==0) {

                                        $$.type=0;

                                        $$.real=$1.real-$3.integer;

                                    }}

        |   term                {$$=$1;}

        ;

term    :   term OP_MULT factor {if($1.type==0 && $3.type==0) {

                                            $$.type=0;

                                            $$.integer=$1.integer*$3.integer;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.real*$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==0 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.integer*$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==0) {

                                        $$.type=0;

                                        $$.real=$1.real*$3.integer;

                                    }}

        |   term OP_DIV factor {if($1.type==0 && $3.type==0) {

                                            $$.type=0;

                                            $$.integer=$1.integer/$3.integer;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.real/$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==0 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=$1.integer/$3.real;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==0) {

                                        $$.type=0;

                                        $$.real=$1.real/$3.integer;

                                    }}

        |   term OP_MOD factor {if($1.type==0 && $3.type==0) {

                                            $$.type=0;

                                            $$.integer=$1.integer%$3.integer;

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=fmod($1.real,$3.real);

                                    }}

        |   factor              {$$=$1;}

        ;

factor  :   primary             {$$=$1;}

        |   primary OP_POW factor   {if($1.type==0 && $3.type==0) {

                                            $$.type=0;

                                            $$.integer=pow($1.integer,$3.integer);

                                    } else if($1.type==1 && $3.type==1) {

                                        $$.type=1;

                                        $$.real=pow($1.real,$3.real);

                                    }}

        ;

primary :   PARENTESIS1 expr PARENTESIS2    {$$=$2;}

        |   PARENTESIS1 OP_REST expr PARENTESIS2    {if($3.type==0) {

                                                        $$.type=0;

                                                        $$.integer=-$3.integer;

                                                    } else if($3.type==1) {

                                                        $$.type=1;

                                                        $$.real=$3.real;

                                                    }}

        |   PARENTESIS1 OP_SUM expr PARENTESIS2 {$$=$3;}

        |   LIT_INT {$$=$1;}

        |   LIT_FLOAT   {$$=$1;}

        |   CADENA  {$$=$1;}

        |   IDENT   {/*sym_lookup($1,$$)*/;}

        ;



%%





void yyerror(char *s)

{

printf("Error %s",s);

}

int main(int argc,char **argv)

{

if (argc>1)

yyin=fopen(argv[1],"rt");

else

yyin=stdin;

yyparse();

printf("FIN del Analisis. Entrada CORRECTA\n");

printf("Numero lineas analizadas: %d\n", num_linea);

return 0;

}
```

This is my flex code:

```
%{

    #include "compilador1.tab.h"

    #include <string.h>

    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <math.h>

    int num_linea;

    extern FILE *yyin;

%}

%option yylineno

%x comentario

%x comentario2

%x str

DIGIT   [0-9]

ID  [a-z][a-z0-9]*



%%

    num_linea=1;

    char string_buf[1000];

    char *string_buf_ptr;

    int string_cnt;



"\n"    {printf("\n");num_linea++;return NX_LINE;}

"\t"    {;}

" "     {;}

"mod"   {return OP_MOD;}

{DIGIT}+    {yylval.num.integer=atoi(yytext);yylval.num.type=0;printf("entero "); return LIT_INT;}

{DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}* {yylval.num.real=atof(yytext);yylval.num.type=1;printf("real "); return LIT_FLOAT;}

{ID}    {yylval.ident.lexema = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*yyleng);

                strncpy(yylval.ident.lexema,yytext,yyleng);

                yylval.ident.lenght = yyleng;

                yylval.ident.line = yylineno;

                printf("id ");

                return IDENT;}

"/" {printf("div ");return OP_DIV;}

"**"    {printf("pow ");return OP_POW;}

"*" {printf("mult ");return OP_MULT;}

"+" {printf("sum ");return OP_SUM;}

"-" {printf("rest ");return OP_REST;}

"(" {printf("( ");return PARENTESIS1;}

")" {printf(") ");return PARENTESIS2;}



":=" {printf("assign ");return ASSIGN;}



"/*"    {BEGIN(comentario);}

<comentario>[^*\n]* /*ignora lo que no sea * */

<comentario>"*"+[^*/\n]*    /*ignora los * no seguidos de / */

<comentario>\n  {++num_linea;}

<comentario>"*"+"/" {BEGIN(INITIAL);}



"//"    {BEGIN(comentario2);}

<comentario2>[^\n]

<comentario2>\n {BEGIN(INITIAL);}



\" string_buf_ptr = string_buf;string_cnt=0; BEGIN(str);

<str>\" { /* saw closing quote - all done */

BEGIN(INITIAL);

*string_buf_ptr = '\0';

/* return string constant token type and

* value to parser

*/

yylval.num.type=2;

yylval.num.string=string_buf_ptr-string_cnt;

printf("string ");

return CADENA;

}

<str>\n {

/* error - unterminated string constant */

/* generate error message */

}

<str>\\n *string_buf_ptr++ = '\n';

<str>\\t *string_buf_ptr++ = '\t';

<str>\\r *string_buf_ptr++ = '\r';

<str>\\b *string_buf_ptr++ = '\b';

<str>\\f *string_buf_ptr++ = '\f';

<str>\\(.|\n) *string_buf_ptr++ = yytext[1];

<str>[^\\\n\"]+ {

char *yptr = yytext;

while ( *yptr ) {

    string_cnt++;

    *string_buf_ptr++ = *yptr++;

}

}

.                   {printf("INVALID: %s", yytext); return INVALID_TOKEN;}

%%
```

And with this input:

```
4+5*6.4+"hello"
4+8
```

I obtain this output:

```
entero sum entero mult real sum string 
El valor es un string y es 36.000000hello. 
entero Error syntax errorFIN del Analisis. Entrada CORRECTA
Numero lineas analizadas: 1
```

What can be my error?

Comment: Too. Much. Code. Please read about the *minimal example*

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code in your Question by focussing on the portion of code that is giving you difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar's start non-terminal is called "linea", and for good reason: it defines exactly one line (*una línea*). Bison parsers recognize precisely the start non-terminal followed by an end-of-file, so if your input contains more than one line, the parser will report a syntax error when it encounters something other than an EOF after the first line.

If you want to recognize multiple lines, you need to write a grammar which matches multiple lines:

```
programa : linea
         | programa linea
```