# trying to implement variables in rply, getting error instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, ply

so I'm trying to find a way to implement variables in rply, but I'm getting an error. since rply errors are awfully vague I've been looking for answers for a long time and didn't get an answer

pastebin of my full grammer [here](https://pastebin.com/sSkPKabW)

my usage:

```
code = "variable_name = 'test'"
iter_tokens = self.lexer.lex(code)
tokens = self.lexer.lex(code)     
for token in iter_tokens:         
    print(token)                  
                                  
self.parser.parse(tokens).eval()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\cassa\python\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\cassa\GitHub\main_folder\zeromay\cogs\custom_commands.py", line 45, in lex_tokens
    self.parser.parse(tokens).eval()
  File "D:\cassa\python\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rply\parser.py", line 61, in parse
    self.error_handler(lookahead)
  File "D:\cassa\GitHub\main_folder\zeromay\utils\pepesharp.py", line 206, in error
    raise ValueError(token)
ValueError: Token('NAME', 'variable_name')
```

Comment: That error seems to be in your parser, not your lexer.

Comment: @rici oh, what information do I need to give for you to help?

Comment: Ideally you would provide a [mre] which focuses on the exact problem you are having. I suspect that your entire project would be way too much code (and far too unfocused to be useful to others), so in an ideal world you would condense it down to a much simpler grammar which exhibits the same error.

Comment: @rici okay. Answer my question

Comment: I did. You need to provide a complete program which I can execute on my machine, which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @rici okay. i edited my question with a pastebin link

Comment: @rici i already showed how im using the code that raises the error

Comment: Yeah, but you don't provide a complete runnable program. The point of a [mre] is that whoever is trying to help you can just copy the code out of your question into a file, run it, and see the problem. They don't have to stitch things together, guess what might need to be imported, etc., etc. Just download, run, and see the error. There's a limited amount of volunteer time available and I'd rather spend it actually doing something constructive. Anyway, never mind. I think I see the problem.

Comment: @rici stop wasting both me and your time by typing those paragraphs. like you said, theres limited amount of volunteer time available and then you end it off with a "nevermind"? if you see a problem, please explain what it is instead of wasting time.

Comment: OK, there you go.

Comment: Also, you will probably want to parse a program with two statements in it, sooner or later. So you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33069324/1566221) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, your entire grammar is here:

```
program : PRINT OPEN_PAREN expression CLOSE_PAREN
program : PRINT OPEN_PAREN program CLOSE_PAREN
program : SEND OPEN_PAREN program COMMA expression CLOSE_PAREN
program : GETCHANNEL OPEN_PAREN expression CLOSE_PAREN
expression : expression SUM expression
expression : expression SUB expression
expression : NAME EQUALS expression
expression : NUMBER
expression : STRING
expression : expression PERIOD
```

The start symbol is `program`, since it's the first production in the grammar. As written, there are four possible program syntaxes, none of which correspond to `name_variable = 'test'`. All four `program` syntaxes start with a keyword, so when the parser sees that the first symbol is `NAME`, it immediately throws a syntax error.

Perhaps you meant to include

```
program : expression
```

in your grammar to make assignment statements (and other expressions) valid statements. If not, you might want to try parsing `print(name_variable = 'test')`, which I think is a valid `program` (although I didn't try it).